# Postfix: I've misconfigured my virtual forwarding, VIRTUAL@com.com is getting my email

Tags: email, postfix, configuration

So I've setup postfix for say `me@example.com`, I then forward emails to that address to my gmail as I don't want to store them on the vps.

My /etc/postfix/virtual has equivalent;

```
me@example.com username@gmail.com
```

Main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_domains = $mydomain
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

When checking logs I can see that emails are being correctly forwarded to my gmail, but then they are also being forwarded to `VIRTUAL@com.com`;

```
Jan 18 12:20:52 <username> postfix/smtp[21811]: 9917D5C3B: to=<VIRTUAL@com.com>, orig_to=<me@<example>.com>, relay=mail.user-mail.net[54.225.106.106]:25, delay=8.2, delays=0.77/0.01/6.9/0.56, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK (1F88FAEC-4D54-4C95-8273-6D9281995827.1) (1F88FAEC-4D54-4C95-8273-6D9281995827.1))
```

I don't want this address to be getting my mail! Where have I messed up my config?

EDIT:

Full main.cf (minus comments):

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $mydomain, $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_alias_maps
virtual_alias_domains = $mydomain
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
            reject_invalid_hostname,
            reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
            reject_unauth_pipelining,
            permit_mynetworks,
            reject_unauth_destination,
            reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
            reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
            reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
            reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
            reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,
            reject_rbl_client dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net,
            permit
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/sslmate/<example>.com.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/sslmate/<example>.com.crt
```

Comment: You should post your full `main.cf` file. Do you see this `VIRTUAL@com.com` address exactly, if not then what?

Comment: @bengal I've edited the OP and added the full config. Yes I see the address VIRTUAL@com.com verbatim in the logs, but not in any configuration I can find

Comment: have you run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` already?

Comment: Yep, and postfix restart.

Comment: Although I've just noticed this in the logs too:

`Jan 18 12:03:13 <username> postfix/cleanup[21648]: warning: database /etc/postfix/virtual.db is older than source file /etc/postfix/virtual`

Comment: Run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` again and restart postfix.

Comment: Same issue;  `Jan 18 14:22:46 jonnypower postfix/smtp[22150]: BD0582A67: to=<VIRTUAL@com.com>, orig_to=<me@jonnypower.com>, relay=mail.user-mail.net[107.21.94.227]:25, delay=14, delays=0.82/0.01/12/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK (0311D6ED-D592-44F6-A59C-CE69CC376EFD.1) (0311D6ED-D592-44F6-A59C-CE69CC376EFD.1))`

Comment: Thought I had worked around it with recipient blacklisting, but that hasn't stopped it either :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34481/discussion-between-autonomy-and-bangal).

Comment: What is the content of the `/etc/postfix/virtual` file?

Comment: Nice, think you've found the issue - just noticed a trailing `VIRTUAL(5)` from the comments at the end of my actual config.

`me@example.com user@gmail.com [100 spaces] VIRTUAL(5)`